# Two inline-block divs are still stacking vertically. (main content is under my sidebar) HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

HTML & CSS question: For this assignment we are not supposed to use floats, but instead only use block, inline-block, and inline. Even though I have set the side-bar div to inline block, and the main-content div to inline-block, and the width less then the wrapper width, It is not aligning left and right. Can anyone please help me understand what I need to fix.
I know this is a lot of code to put in here, but I am not sure what I need to put in, and what I don't. I looked around and tried to find an answer but if this question has already been asked and solved please reference me. Thanks.

[Google drive of the html and css (sorry to have to send the whole file, I was not sure what it was so I decided to attach the whole html and css file.)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1cxsuKTipwYfktFYV9wQm9IWk1PUWV2RHNwMWZiWldhRlViNGJpZGlDSERYVFdoV3lERUU&usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you try to make a *minimal* example? Do you succeed in just aligning two divs next to each other if you make them inline block? If so, work from there, if not, you've got your minimal example right there and you can ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Word Stream</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Pay per click search marketing software offers a means for accomplishing two core requirments for PPC optimization"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Header (Logo and Nav) -->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">AdWords Grader</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form id ="login">
                    <label>
                        <button class="button" type="button">Login</button>
                    </label>
                </form>         
            </div>

            <div id="logo">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
                <span id="word">Word</span>
                <span id="stream">Stream</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main content section -->
        <div id="main-page">
            <div id="banner">
                <h1>WordStream Internet Marketing Software</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- main side of page -->

            <!-- Side bar (info and Advertisment) -->
            <div id="side-bar">
                <div id="side-bar-content">
                    <h1>Wordstream for PPC</h1>
                    <h2>Drive More Profits Through PPC!</h2>
                    <p>Get Started with <span class="blue">Wordstream</span>'s Powerful PPC Platform Today</p>
                    <form>
                        <label>
                            <button class="button1" type="button">SCHEDULE DEMO</button>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <button class="button2" type="button">FREE TRIAL</button>
                        </label>
                    </form>
                    <p class="center">(No Credit Card Required)</p>
                </div>
                <!-- side bar ad -->
                <div id="side-bar-ad">
                    <div id="wrap-img-text">
                        <h3>How does your adWords performance measure up?</h3>
                        <p>Get a free, instant report with the WordStream Adwords Performance Grader</p>
                        <form>
                            <label>
                                <button class="graded" type="button">Get Graded Today</button>
                            </label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <img class="img" src="left_content_ad1.png" alt="Oops, your browser isn't showing this image.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="handle">
            <div id="upper-bar">
                <img class="inline" src="home_button.png" alt="home">
                <span class="blue">PPC</span>
                <!-- contact info and phone pic -->
                <div id="contact" class="inline">
                    <img class="inline phone" src="phone.png" alt="phone">
                    <!-- text only -->
                    <div class="inline">
                        <p class="top">
                            <span class="hours">Mon - Fri 9 a.m. - 5 p.m. (EST)</span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="number">855.967.3787</span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="int-number">International: +1.617.963.0555</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><br/>
            <!-- main content starts here -->
            <div id="main-content">
                <h1>PPC - Achieve More Efficiant Pay-Per CLick (PPC) Marketing</h1>
                <p><span class="bold">PPC</span>(<a href="#">pay-per click</a>) search marketing software offers a means for accomplishing two core requirements for PPC optimization:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="bold">PPC Automation</span>-While it would be impossible (and inadvisable!) to automate every aspect of <a href="#">pay-per-click advertising</a>, automating away redundant, time-consuming tasks affords you a means of increasing productivity. Often, this means being able to produce an amount of work that would otherwise have been unachievable for you and your business.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="bold">PPC Management</span>-<a href="#">PPC management</a> refers to the maintenance and prioritizing of <a href="#">paid seach</a> marketing tasks. Being able to oversee various aspects of your account while assigning each item on a seemingly endless to-do list an appropriate value can make or break an <a href="#">online ad campaign</a>.
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p>
                    WordStream's <a href="#">PPC software</a> is specifically designed to aid in these two <a href="#">PPC search engine</a> marketing areas. This page will show you both the processes the software is automating for you, and the best course of action to take where workflow is concerned.
                </p>
                <!-- Bordered *Trial* box with logo and button -->
                <div id="trial-box">
                    <img src="content_ad.png" alt="ad">
                    <div class="text-button">
                        <h3>Drive More Profits Through PPC - Try Our Platform FREE</h3>
                        <p>Get instant access to WordStream's innovative <span class="bold"> Quality Score</span> and <span class="bold">Account Management</span> tools through our <span class="bold"> FREE 7-day Trial</span>. Risk Free, No Credit Card Required and No Automatic Signups.</p>
                        <form>
                            <label>
                                <button class="get-started" type="button">Get Started Today!</button>
                            </label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- under the trial box -->
                <h2>Automation And Your PPC Search Campaign</h2>
                <p>Another two lines of text that I really dont feel like copying. Soooo much text to copy, not worth it. Im just writing this instead to fill in the space.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
#wrapper{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
/*HEader things*/
#header{
width: auto;
position: relative;
height: 100px;
}
#logo{
display: block;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
#logo img{
vertical-align: text-bottom;
width: 50px;
}
#word{
color: grey;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 35px;
}
#stream{
color: blue;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 35px;
}
#nav{
display: block;
margin: 10px 30px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
#nav ul{
display: inline-block;
background-color: #F0F0F0;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 0px 10px 5px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
}
#nav li{
display: inline-block;
font-size: 12px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#login{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.button{
width: 60px;
height: 25px;
background-color: blue;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 0px;
color: white;
}
/*Banner right under header*/
#banner{
background-color: blue;
padding: 5px 10px;
margin: 15px 0px;
font-size: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 50px 200px grey;
}
#banner h1{
color: white
}
/*sidebar*/
#side-bar{
display: inline-block;
width: 220px;
}
#side-bar-content{
border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#side-bar h1{
font-size: 15px;
color: blue;
}
#side-bar h2{
font-size: 12px;
color: darkred;
}
#side-bar p{
font-size: 11px;
}
.button1{
border: 0px;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
width: 220px;
padding: 3px 0px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.button2{
border: 0px;
background-color: orange;
color: white;
width: 220px;
padding: 3px 0px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.center{
text-align: center;
}
/*Bottom half of sidebar*/
#side-bar-ad{
position: relative;
}
#wrap-img-text{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
#wrap-img-text h3{
font-size: 15px;
padding: 5px;
color: blue;
}
#wrap-img-text p{
padding: 3px;
}
.graded{
width: 180px;
background-color: darkblue;
color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 5px;
}
.img{
width: 210px;
height: auto;
}
.blue {
color: blue;
}
#handle{
    vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;
}
/*Under the panel (phone number etc)*/
#upper-bar{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
width: 720px;
height: 110px;
border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
#upperbar hr{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
.inline{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
#contact{
position: absolute;
height: 110px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
.phone{
height: 70%;
width: auto;
}
.number{
color: blue;
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
font-size: 45px;
}
.int-number{
font-size: 15px;
}
/*main content section*/
#main-content{
display: inline-block;
width: 700px;
vertical-align: top;
}
#main-content li{
list-style-type: square;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 5px
}
#main-content h1{
font-size: 23px;
color: blue;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
#main-content p{
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
.bold{
 font-weight: bold;
}
#trial-box{
border: 5px solid blue;
padding: 10px;
}
#trial-box img{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.text-button{
display: inline-block;
width: 600px;
vertical-align: top;
}
h3{
color: blue;
}
.get-started{
background-color: limegreen;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 0px;
width: 150px;
padding: 5px;
}
h2{
color: blue;
font-size: 17px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Check out this

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mxnzn57/)

**EDIT:**

**Q:Why the code didn't work before?**
A:[image]

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks for the edit for more info. However I just looked through it a little more and I realized that yours did fix it, however I needed it to look slightly different. This is what the assignment asked the site to look like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1cxsuKTipwYaFBFaE5sY2tuX2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for the help though, I'm sorry about all the confusion its just I am brand new to this and been stuck on this problem for quite a while, and its really frustrating me that its not working ;-p I just can't understand what is wrong with my code. :/

Comment: Thank you, But would you mind explaining why it wouldn't work before and why your change fixed it. I would like to understand for the future if you wouldn't mind quickly explaining what I was doing wrong.